# How can I select a random instance from FaunaDB?

Tags: database, random, faunadb

FaunaDB allows me to index data items by individual fields, and to paginate through indexes, but I don't see a way to select a random item.

Answer (score 2):

Selecting a random item at scale is tough in any database. There are two main techniques to choose from depending on your requirements.

1. Define and use an index for your query. This gives you full control over behavior like selecting the same item twice, etc.
2. Piggyback on an existing index. This is more useful for development tasks, where you just want to see a random-ish record, but aren't concerned about fair distribution.

Whichever you choose, you'll end up wanting the [FaunaDB index documentation](https://fauna.com/documentation/objects#indexes). For option 2, this [Activity feed tutorial](https://fauna.com/tutorials/activity_feed) contains plenty of examples of index event queries.

#### Random Index

Maintain a field on each instance that contains a random number, and use it as an index value.  Then paginate over values, to a random start key. This method allows the same item to be chosen multiple times by the random process.

It can be extended for more control by adding an integer field to count the number of time the instance has been picked. You can increment the count in the same transaction that selects the instance. By using the selection-count as an index term, you can then query for a random item that has been chosen zero times. Once you have chosen all your items once, you can repeat with the `1` term to start selecting items which have been chosen once, but not twice.

#### Existing Index

Data is FaunaDB is temporal, so you can use the temporal features to select instances in a way that may be random enough, depending on your use case.

If you want to take advantage of an index you already have, and don't actually care about fair randomness, but just want a cheap way to check out different instances in your data set, you can paginate from a random timestamp during the lifespan of your app, using the events view, and sample different instances in your class.

Using a termless class index, you'll be selecting instances from the whole class, but it can also work for selecting instances within a single term of an index with terms.

If some time periods have a heavy balance of your write activity (the recent past, for a rapidly growing service) you may want to bias your synthetic cursor toward the heavy periods.